# Delimited Continuations: Easy? or Fundamentally Difficult?

Tags: functional-style, meta-programming

Apologies in advance for the length of this question, but this is as short as I have been able to make it.

### The Prescription

I'm looking at the following tutorial on delimited (or composable)
continuations:

http://community.schemewiki.org/?composable-continuations-tutorial

The author(s) propose the following "rewrite rules"

```
;; RULE 1 ;;
 (reset (...A... (shift K E) ...B...))
 ; -->
 (let ((K (lambda (x) (reset (...A... x ...B...)))))
   (reset E)) ;; You may call K in here!

;; RULE 2 ;;
 (reset E)
 ; -->
 E
```

This is somewhat backed up by equations 2 and 3 on page 100 of Shan's paper,
http://tinyurl.com/q7ebt4a. Qualifications of "somewhat" make up the center of my
question below, after some more motivation and examples.

### Motivating Examples

I can rephrase the above in a pair of slogans:

1. The argument of a delimited continuation `K` replaces the `shift` in a fresh
   copy of the original reset
2. The body `E` of the shift, in a fresh reset, replaces the original reset.

The rules above can be directly written and played with in Mathematica, and that
would be grand. Here is a first attempt:

```
reset[h_[As___, shift[k_, E_], Bs___]] :=
  Block[{K = Function[x, reset[h[As, x, Bs]]]},
   reset[E /. {k -> K}]]
reset[E_] := E
```

Here are a few examples pulled from papers:

```
reset[1 + shift[k, k[42]]]
reset[1 + shift[k, k[k[42]]]]
{a, reset[{b, shift[k, k[k[{1, {c}}}]]}]}
ClearAll[$g$];
reset[1 + shift[k, Function[$g$ = k]]][];
$g$[42]
reset[1 + shift[k, "zork"]]
reset[{1, shift[k, k[20]], shift[k, k[30]]}]

 > 43
 > 44
 > {a, {b, {b, {1, {c}}}}}
 > 43
 > "zork"
 > {1, 20, 30}
```

This would be really cool for concurrent state machines or lazy streams or
reactive patterns and more.

### It May Not Be Right

The problem is that I don't think it's right because it doesn't look any deeper
than first level.  Ironically, every example I have seen in the literature only
has shifts at level 1 of the expression inside the reset, **BUT**

If I fire up Racket (a modernized Scheme), do `(require racket/control)` and
then

```
(reset (+ 1 (shift k (k 42)))

 > 43
```

as expected and as consistent with the above.  If I do

```
(reset (+ 1 (* 2 (shift k (k 42)))))

 > 85
```

this looks intuitively right, but doesn't match the prescription above. That
prescription, if I read it correctly, should lead to the second rewrite rule and
just produce `(+ 1 (* 2 (shift k (k 42))))` because it can't "see" the `shift`
at the second level, "inside" the `(* 2 (shift ...))` subexpression.

Of course, my Mathematica version matches the prescription:

```
reset[1 + 2 * shift[k, k[42]]]

 > 1 + 2 shift[k, k[42]]
```

### Is an Easy Solution Possible?

I now think that Shan's paper above is being too glib, with an imaginary
*context* operator that lets `shift` refer to a `reset` at higher levels.

Everything else I've been able to find on implementing delimited continuations
is vastly larger and would be a lot of very sideways work
(http://tinyurl.com/oec83ky, http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4313),
requiring one ore more of the following:

1. Haskell's monad library
2. Scheme's `call/cc` or idiosyncratic macro system
3. Building your own VM for stack-hacking and caching (http://tinyurl.com/n9kz5fb)
4. Rewriting your whole program into CPS (continuation-passing style), either
   manually or by writing a metacircular translator, e.g.,
   http://tinyurl.com/bo8zl9c)
5. Building your language up from a tiny lambda calculus in CPS (fig. 1, p. 101
   in http://tinyurl.com/q7ebt4a)
6. Throw and Catch, considered desirable to avoid

I have spent a lot of time trying to get the above working with recursive
equations (see junk code below), but I am now despairing that it's not easy. A
`shift` at a lower level might refer to a matching `reset` at a higher level,
which must be threaded around the equations in one way or another.

Now, finally to the actual question of this post:

### Am I blindly missing an easy way in Mathematica?

I would like to avoid `Throw` and `Catch` in favor of a functional solution, because I have been led to believe that delimited continuations are actual, ordinary functions, unlike continuations, which are jumps that (confusingly) look like functions, and because `Throw` and `Catch` are too close to Scheme's `call/cc`, which I definitely want to avoid (if I don't avoid it, I might as well use Scheme and not Mathematica, after all).

### Broken Junk Code

May have some useful ideas, however.

```
ClearAll[u, v, r, q, s];
v[cc_, cc_[E_]] := E;
u[cc_, cc_[E_]] := E;
u[cc_, h_[As___]] :=
  With[{xs = Select[{As}, Head[#] === cc &]},
   If[{} =!= xs,
    v[cc, First[xs]],
    xs]];
u[cc_, E_] := E;

r[E_] := Module[{cc = Unique["cc"]},
   u[cc, q[cc, E]]];

q[cc_, h_[As___, s[k_, E_], Bs___]] :=
  Module[{K = x \[Function] r[h[As, x, Bs]]},
   r[cc[E /. {k -> K}]]];

q[cc_, h_[As___]] :=
  With[{qs = q[cc, #] & /@ {As}},
   h[Sequence @@ qs]];

q[cc_, Function[E_]] := Function[E]

q[cc_, E_] := cc[E]
```